# Keyboard IME with emojis

Tags: android, ime, android-keypad

I am making a keyboard with custom images which i have to "copy to clipboard" when clicked. I have followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) for making a working keyboard. On press a key i am also able to change keyboard layout. Now i want to change background and font of each keys of keyboard and also i want to add given images in gridview. I googled things but couldn't find the perfect one.

Any link for tutorial will also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can only use emojis available using UNICODE characters. You can add your custom images  but only in your app and not with all apps

Comment: can i add only images as background? I can make particular image copied into clipboard than.

Comment: There is no problem in adding images to your keyboard. Problem is other apps may or may not have functionality to handle your image when inputted through keyboard. However if you have to copy to clipboard that should be possible then but I haven't tried copying part

Comment: yes i know. but how?